# Data insertion is quite slow will partitioning can support?

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, partitioning

- I am having a decade old table, which stores the data of all customers.
- I usually insert the customer data once in every 15 mins
- The problem is insert took long time, whereas same data took less time while inserted into another identical table which is empty.

Any suggestions ??

Comment: *The problem is insert took long time* What is the execution plan of the `INSERT`? Do you have triggers on this table? Do you have 9001 indexes? Do you insert all rows at once or RBAR?

Comment: no triggers ..
no indexes..
inserting data using ssis ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will partitioning can support?

No.

You have a performance problem so you first have to identify the root cause. Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/), apply the methods described there to identify wait times and then address the specific bottlenecks you discover.